# case statement syntax to check input existence in multiple file paths

Tags: bash

I have input list with full enterprise host list(`/home/completehostlistcheck.txt`). Depending on which environment it lies (compare the input from `dev=/home/dev.txt` and `prod=/home/prod.txt`) run `echo` and say which environment it lies. Problem is case syntax is not working

```
#!/bin/bash

dev=/home/dev.txt
prod=/home/prod.txt

for host in $(</home/completehostlistcheck.txt) 
do 
ssh $host

chk=$hostname
  case "$chk" in
dev) echo "this is dev"
;;
prod) echo "this is prod"
;;

esac 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the differences between your development hosts and your production hosts, or if there's a simple naming convention (e. g. `dev.example.com` vs. `prod.example.com`), this could be as simple as:

```
for host in $(</home/completelistlistcheck.txt); do
    case "$(ssh $host hostname)" in
        *dev*)
            env="development"
            break
            ;;
        *prod*)
            env="production"
            break
            ;;
        *)
            env="non-categorized"
            break
            ;;
    esac
    echo "$host is a $env host."
done
```

If there is a file on each host that you're needing to parse the contents of, use `cat /path/to/file` rather than `hostname` in the command run via `ssh`.

Comment: Let me make it this way, I have 4 host environments, A, B, C and D. There is one input list which has total of 50 hostnames, So now, all I need to do is first grab the first hostname from input list, match it to environment (A,B,C or D) and then run a script depending on the environment it belongs to. If first host belongs to environment A, then script1, else if it belongs to environment B then script 2
FYI., A, B, C and D all have few hosts which should be one among those 50

Comment: @user227863 Can you tell us how you currently match a hostname to its environment? The code in your question has `chk=$hostname` and then assumes `$chk` is something like `"dev"`, but there's no code shown that sets `hostname`.

Comment: So when I save envrionment A, B, C and D. It means they are some file location, A : /home/dev.txt, B /home/prod.txt, C /home/test.txt which have list of hosts. So input list which I give initially should look at all these environments text files (file paths A, B, C and D), find a input and run script depending on the envrionment. Let me know if this is clear now. And sorry, I should have mentioned it more clearly. Any help is much appreciated. FYI., I'm looking to get this worked using case statement only

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

**hostname**

Unless your login makes sure that this variable exists you should use the command `hostname` instead:

```
chk=$(hostname)
```

**ssh**

`ssh $host` just makes a login and waits for terminal input then. The following command is executed after `ssh` exits. You have to add a command to the `ssh` call. It would be a bit much to pass the whole `case` stuff to `ssh` but as I understand it you need only the result of `hostname`:

```
chk="(ssh "$host" hostname)"
```

Comment: Let me make it this way,  I have 4 host environments, A, B, C and D. There is one input list which has total of 50 hostnames, So now, all I need to do is first grab the first hostname from input list, match it to environment (A,B,C or D) and then run a script depending on the environment it belongs to. If first host belongs to environment A, then script1, else if it belongs to environment B then script 2